# How to change notification key of setting bundle through our app in ios?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have an app I want to change notification service through our app and it should reflect in setting also. I know I can do it with `[defaults setObject:@"" forKey:@""]`, but I dont know what would be the object and key for push notification

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the key for push notification i.e.  "enableNotification".